# RESTful API to get around origin policy

Tags: javascript, json, html, rest

Is there a RESTful API that can be used to get around the same domain origin policy? Something along the lines of http://restful-http-get.com/get?url=http://google.com&callback=datareceived and then I could have a JavaScript function that gets the source of http://google.com?

```
function datareceived(googlesource){
    alert(googlesource);
}
```

So basically the server would place the request and send it back as JSON-P so that I don't have to worry about the same domain origin policy on AJAX requests.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsonp.jit.su/

That said, please consider very carefully whether you really want to do this. The same origin policy exists for a good reason.

Comment: This is good but it only works when the URL returns JSON. Try using it with google.com...

Comment: You're right. It does coincidentally return JSONP with the source of the page, but as part of a 502 Bad Gateway response, so the browser refuses to load the script.